# JWT auth flow using access token and refresh token

Tags: authentication, web, jwt, access-token

I'm working on a project (nothing production-level, only for leveling up my skills) and I'm using JWT to handle authentication.
From what I've read, using a JWT only as an access token is quite unsafe, and hence we need refresh tokens. So, on login, the server returns an access token and a refresh token (which I will be storing in an httpOnly cookie). The access token expires in a short time, but the refresh token is used to get a new one when it does.

My question is, when do we use the refresh token to get a new access token? Is it when the user wants to get a protected resource and finds that the access token is expired (and the refresh token has not) or do we send a new access token each time the user wants to get the protected resource? I'm confused about when and where the refresh token comes into play.

(I'm using React for the frontend and Nodejs for the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using some security token so it mean that your system has some protected resources. Those resources can only be accessible on successful validation of the token. As you're using the JWT Token (usually for stateless authentication) and your system is granting both `access_token` and `refresh_token` to the client, so on server side you can use some authentication interceptor to validate the access_token in the each private request and return some error code on token expiration. On the client side you could also use some filter which should capture the error code and by utilizing the available refresh_token it should request for new access_token from the server. In case of refresh_token expiration your system should follow the route of fresh authentication.

Answer (score 2):

The refresh token can be used at any time to request a new access token.  Checking the validity of the access token before he request is one way of accomplishing that.  Another common practice is to refresh the access token if it is within a certain timeframe of the current token expiring.  A simple cronjob can work in this case. If you assume the access token is not used in multiple places (which it shouldn't be) then the current access token can be invalidated when the new access token is created.  Also, for maximum security, the refresh token should be replaced with the access token.  This limits security risk around a long-living refresh token becoming compromised.